# How to achieve bucketing concept using ora-hash function

Tags: sql, oracle

I've researched on the Internet but couldn't find an answer.

How to achieve the bucketing concept using the ora-hash function could you please guide me?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Bucketing implies a physical segregation of data for the purposes of improving performance. The way to do that for very large tables in Oracle is through table partitioning. See here: https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/vldbg/index.html

Answer (score 2):

"Using `ORA_HASH` function" only *approximates* bucketing; you can decide the number of buckets, and use `ORA_HASH` to assign entities to buckets, but there is no guarantee that the assignment will be balanced. It should be "more or less" balanced (approximately equal numbers of entities assigned to each bucket), but it won't be exact. So, first question: **Why does it have to be `ORA_HASH` and not some other method?**

With that said, here is one way to do what you asked. (Noting again that "what you asked" doesn't make very much sense in the first place.) Suppose you have the 14 employees in the standard `SCOTT.EMP` table and you must assign them (randomly) to three buckets. `ORA_HASH` creates buckets numbered from 0 to N (where you give N as an input to the function); if you want the buckets to be 1, 2, 3, then you should run `ORA_HASH` with N = 2 (to create buckets 0, 1, 2) and then add 1 to the result so the buckets are numbered 1, 2, 3.

Other than that, you can apply ORA_HASH to many data types. One dumb idea is to, then, apply ORA_HASH to the employee's last name (for example). It's dumb because last names generally aren't distinct; there are many Smith and Jones (in the U.S.) and very few Pryxz, so whichever bucket has Smith will likely have many more employees that other buckets (because ORA_HASH assigns a bucket to the *name*, not to the *employee*). You must apply ORA_HASH to something unique about each employee; for example to the `EMPNO`, or - even simpler - to the Oracle-generated `ROWNUM`.

```
select 1 + ora_hash(rownum, 2) as bucket, ename
from   scott.emp
order  by bucket, ename
;

BUCKET  ENAME     
------  ----------
     1  ALLEN     
     1  FORD      
     1  JONES     
     1  MARTIN    
     1  MILLER    
     2  ADAMS     
     2  CLARK     
     2  JAMES     
     2  KING      
     2  SCOTT     
     3  BLAKE     
     3  SMITH     
     3  TURNER    
     3  WARD
```